Quantizing the electric field without quantizing vector potential
I am trying to quantize the electromagnetic field, without using the vector potential. I start with a Fourier expansion:
$$\begin{equation}
\vec{E}(\vec{r},t) = \sum_{\epsilon} \vec{\epsilon} \int \frac{d\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3} \ a_\epsilon (\vec{k},t) e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}
\end{equation}$$
Then plug this expression into source-free Maxwell's wave equation $[\nabla^2 - \partial^2_t/c^2] E = 0$ to get:
$$\partial^2_t a_\epsilon (k,t) = -(kc)^2 a_\epsilon (k,t)$$
which has a general solution:
$$a_\epsilon (k,t) = a_k e^{-i\omega_k t} + b_k e^{+i\omega_k t}$$
where the polarization $\epsilon$ is suppressed on the RHS for brevity. Now I impose the reality condition $a_\epsilon(k,t) = a^\dagger_\epsilon(-k,t)$ to get $b_k=a^{\dagger}_{-k}$. Also, to preserve Lorentz invariance I modify the integration measure, giving finally:
$$E(r,t) = \sum \epsilon\int \frac{dk}{(2\pi)^3 \sqrt{2\omega_k}} \Big[a_k e^{-i\omega_k t} + a^{\dagger}_{-k} e^{+i\omega_k t}\Big] e^{ikr}$$
The canonical commutation relations can now be applied between $E$ and it's time derivative $\dot{E}$:
$$ \dot{E}(r,t) =  \sum \epsilon \int (-i) \frac{dk}{(2\pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{\omega_k}{2}} \Big[a_k e^{-i\omega_k t} - a^{\dagger}_{-k} e^{+i\omega_k t}\Big] e^{ikr}$$
$$[E(r,t),  \dot{E}(r',t)] = i \delta(r-r')$$
These result in the following commutation relation between the creation/annihilation operators:
$$[a_k,a^\dagger_{k'}] = (2\pi)^3 \delta_{k,k'}$$
So far, everything works well. It can be shown easily that the $E(r,t)$ operator creates an excitation that is localized at $r$.
Now, I am trying to compute the Hamiltonian for this theory, in terms of the operators $a_k$ and $a^\dagger_k$. However, when I compute $\int dr \vert E \vert^2$, I do not get anything that resembles an energy term. Where am I going wrong?
UPDATE:
I have now quantized the $B$ field as well. For the source-free case ($\rho$=0, $J$=0), the magnetic and electric fields satisfy the same wave equation, and are related by:
$$\nabla \times E = -\partial_t B$$
$$\sum (i k\times \epsilon) \Big[a_k e^{-i\omega_k t} + a^{\dagger}_{-k} e^{i\omega_k t}\Big] = \sum \xi \Big[-i\omega_k c_k e^{-i\omega_k t} + i\omega_k  c^{\dagger}_{-k} e^{i\omega_k t}\Big]$$
$$\sum_j (\epsilon_j \times i k) a_k  = \sum_j i \omega_k \xi_j c_k $$
$$\vert k \vert a_k  = \omega_k c_k \ \ \text{and} \ \ \xi_j = \epsilon_j \times \hat{k}$$
where $B$ is expanded similar to $E$, with $a_k \to c_k$ and the polarization vectors $\epsilon \to \xi$. We can thus conclude the that $B$ field is always orthogonal to the $E$ field, and $c_k = a_k/c$. Thus, the problem persists. The full Hamiltonian now reads:
$$H = \frac{\epsilon_0}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{dk}{\omega_k} (a_k a^\dagger_k + a^\dagger_k a_k + a_k a_{-k} e^{-2i\omega_k t} + a^\dagger_{-k} a^\dagger_{k} e^{2i\omega_k t})$$
What I fail to see is why these $a_k$,$a^\dagger_k$ operators are any different that the ones used in the standard textbook treatment, given that they obey the same commutation relationship as the ladder operators.

Your $a_k$ is not the same as their $a_k$. They differ by factors of $\omega$.

Does that mean that my hamiltonian will look different as well?


I do not get anything that resembles an energy term.  Why do you think computing that integral should resemble an energy term? Energy needs to be defined, e.g. based on some Hamiltonian operator (which one do you assume?) or based on a local conservation law n classical theory, where one term can be understood as work and the other interpreted as energy density and energy flux density (e.g. in case of regular charge distributions, the Poynting theorem, and then EM energy is integral of square of electric field plus integral of square of magnetic field).


I am assuming $H = \int dr \Big[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \vert E \vert^2 + \frac{1}{2 \mu_0} \vert B \vert^2\Big]$. Maybe once I calculate $\vert B \vert^2$, the total expression will look like an energy.
